# Who repairs a two week MacBook Air cracked screen without Apple Care+?

Tags: mac, screen, applecare

I opened the lid yesterday morning and the screen was unresponsive (black) and cracked on one corner (4cm). Apple says that the only alternative is to contract Apple Care+ (300€) and they will cover this damage. Should they repair this for free, being that new the laptop?

Answer (score 2):

Warranty is for manufacture failure. Insurance is for accidental damage. AppleCare+ is actually a bit of both.

Proving a screen broke 'all on its own' is going to be extremely tough. I'd check your regular household insurance coverage for 'accidental damage'.

*<sup>A bit of insider knowledge goes a long way here;) If you claim this on insurance, they will likely impose a lien on any future claim - i.e if they give you 2 grand now & you break another one, the first 1500 will be on you next time.

So, you take the 2 grand from the insurance - in your hand, or in the bank, not in vouchers & not in any "we'll pay for it" or "give us your old one" manner. You want the 2 grand **and** the broken computer in your hand.

You take this 2 grand & the broken computer to an Apple Store [not a 3rd party] & ask them if the broken one has any trade-in value. Also request that they safely destroy any data on the old one [this is why you take it to Apple, who are trustworthy in this].

You take the trade-in value, give them the rest of the money out of your 2 grand… & pocket the change [or keep it against that lien they imposed for if there's a next time.]

This is all actually legal & above board, but don't try it twice.</sup>*

Comment: I always thought you got 3 months AppleCare free, as standard.

Comment: Yeah, but what they're asking the OP to buy is AppleCare+ It's the + that adds the insurance factor. Basic AppleCare will cover 'acts of god' but not 'acts of dog' ;) i.e not accidental damage. In fact, in the UK [& likely all across the EU], that basic warranty isn't worth the paper it's not printed on. Standard consumer rights are more powerful - but still no acts of dog.